# iOS - Container components in different storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard, uicontainerview

I want to make a container which will be in a single storyboard and each component view will be in different storyboard. For example, Container storyboard will be in Home.storyboard and component A and B will be in A.storyboard and B.storyboard respectively. Can anyone guide me how to implement this in Swift?

[image]

In this above container component-A and component-B are in the same storyboard along with main container. I want to create different storyboard for both components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the solution. We need to refactor the components into new storyboard.

1. Select component A view controller
2. Xcode Menu -> Editor -> Refactor to Storyboard...
3. Select a proper name and save it

[image]

New storyboard, ComponentA will contain only the component view with a initial view controller mark. New Storyboard will look like below.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can use **Storyboard Reference**. Storyboard Reference has a name to which storyboard it points and an identifier for UIViewController in that storyboard.

[image]

Move Component 1 and Component 2 to separate storyboards. From Object Library drag `storyboard references`. Attach Segue to Storyboard Reference. Give the name of Storyboard to each Storyboard Reference.

[image]

In this way you can separate Storyboards

Comment: How to add this storyboard reference?

Comment: @SazzadHissainKhan Edited with little more detail

Answer (score 2):

If you want to initialize the controllers from another storyboard, you could do it like this:

```
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Storyboard_B", bundle: nil)
    if let aViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AViewController") as? UIViewController {
        //do something about aViewController
    }
```

And in Storyboard B you need to set identifiy of ViewController:

[image]